# How to readjust defaultdict(list)s - Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples, defaultdict

I need a defaultdict that can do get the `finaldict` given a list of query words from the first file.

The final dict is a dictionary of a pair of words from both files that shares the same ID. e.g. `foo, oof` shares the same `1243` and `1453` ID. It is to facilitate word-pair search later, when i try to search `('foo','oof')`, it will return `['1243','1453']`.
If i search the finaldict for `('foo','duh')`, it will return nothing as the wordpair don't share any same ID.

```
query = ['foo','barbar']

finaldict = defaultdict(list)

finaldict = {('foo','oof'):['1243','1453']
('foo','rabrab'):['2323']
('barbar','duh'):['6452']}
```

I've been doing it as below but **is there a simpler way of achieving the `finaldict`?**

```
query = ['foo','barbar']
from collections import defaultdict

dict1 = defaultdict(list)
dict2 = defaultdict(list)

dict1['foo'] = ['1234','1453','2323']; 
dict1['bar'] =['5230']; dict1['barbar'] =['6452']

dict2['1243']=['oof']
dict2['1453']=['oof']
dict2['4239']=['rba']
dict2['2323']=['rabrab']
dict2['6452']=['duh']

tt = defaultdict(defaultdict)
for p in sorted(query):
  for ss in sorted(dict1[p]):
    if len(dict2[ss]) != 0 and dict2[ss] != None:
      tt[p][ss] = dict2[ss]

finaldict = defaultdict(set)

for src in tt:
  for ss in tt[src]:
    for trg in tt[src][ss]:
      finaldict[(src, trg)].add(ss)

print finaldict[('foo','oof')]
```

The above code outputs:

```
>>> print finaldict[('foo','oof')]
set(['1453'])
>>> for i in finaldict:
...     print i, finaldict[i]
... 
('foo', 'rabrab') set(['2323'])
('barbar', 'duh') set(['6452'])
('foo', 'oof') set(['1453'])
```

Comment: I'm really not understanding the criteria for creating `finaldict`.  Could you try to describe that a little better?

Comment: updated the purpose of `finaldict`, is it clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{(k1,v):k2 for k1 in dict1 for k2 in dict2 
           for v in dict2[k2] if k2 in dict1[k1]}
```

{('barbar', 'duh'): '6452', ('foo', 'oof'): '1453', ('foo', 'rabrab'): '2323'}